# Quick question about Archimedian property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> **Archimedean Property** $\;$ If $x\in\mathbb{R},$ then there exists $n_x\in\mathbb N$ such that $x<n_x.$ 
>  
>  **Proof** (By contradiction.) If not, then $x$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb N$; consequently, there is a least upper bound for $\mathbb N$, say $u=\sup\mathbb N$. 
>  Now $u-1\lt u=\sup\mathbb N$ implies that there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $m>u-1$. But since $m+1\in\mathbb N$ and $m+1\gt u,$ this contradicts $u=\sup\mathbb N.$

Could someone tell me why we can't have $m \geq u-1$? Why do we assume $u - 1 \notin \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Where does it assume $u\notin \mathbb N$? (It's obvious that $u=\sup \mathbb N$ is not in $\mathbb N$, but we nowhere assume that.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) Here the strict inequality $m>u-1$ comes from the definition of sup: if $a<\sup A$, then there exists some $a'\in A$ such that $a'>a$, since if $a'\le a$ for all $a'\in A$, then $a$ is an upper bound of $A$, implying that $a\ge \sup A$ as $\sup A$ is the **least** upper bound.

(2) We do not assume $u-1\notin \mathbb{N}$. Actually this does not play any role in our proof, does it?

Comment: I just thought that since $u -1$ isn't an integer, $m$ may not equal to $u -1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is the supremum, then $u-1$ is strictly less than it, so there must exist $m$ strictly greater than $u-1$ (because $u$, and not $u-1$, is the supremum). Doesn't matter if $u-1\in\mathbb{N}$, only matters that there must be *more* naturals beyond it.

Answer (score 0):

We don't assume anything about $u-1$. It is **stricly less** than the $\sup$, so it cannot dominate (be bigger than or equal) all naturals. So there must be a natural number that is **strictly bigger** than it.

Comment: Stupid question, but if sup did belong to $N$, then does this mean there is no point in this proof?

Comment: If it did, it would be the maximum of $\mathbb{N}$, and then you would just add $1$ to it and contradict its maximality.

Comment: But the argument in the proof  would not change as this maximum is still a supremum.

Comment: @sidht It is the existence of the supremum (because we assume the existence of an upper bound) that makes the proof work, nothing else.

Comment: Can $m \leq u$? That is can $m$ be equal to $u$?

Comment: Under your (FALSE) extra assumption that $u$ could be natural, yes. We don't have to get into the nature of $\sup$ (natural or not). We just showed directly the existence of a NATURAL $m$ such that $m>u-1$.